# How can I make 3D graphic in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt

First, I'm new in Java.
Second, sorry for my English but I'm still learning it.
I need to create object in 3D space, which I would can manipulate from my mouse next.

I can make e.g. square like this:

```
        public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);           
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 40, 40);
        }
```

But what I can do with that? In my opinion its only contour. Have Java special class for that?
I can use only awt;* and derivative from that. Is Canvas3D count to that?

Please, help me:)

Comment: You could use OpenGL

Comment: There's nothing in the AWT/Swing libraries which is capable of doing that sort of thing, you'll need to generate the code entirely yourself. There are ways to fake it, but that's some complex maths

Comment: You could have a look at [Java3D Graphics](http://www.java3d.org/)

Comment: You could also have a look at [Java 3D](https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html) (different library)

Comment: But none of these libraries will mix well with Swing

Comment: Thanks for comments.
Well, should I make that in Java3D and open without JFrame (Swing)? Its correct?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mjmcguff/learn/java/11-3d/) if you really want to use awt only and do the math yourself. Its an Java applet that draws a 3d cube that can be rotated with mouse. It should be easy to translate it into java application using a JFrame.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [jogl](http://jogamp.org/jogl-demos/www/) in my projects

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use JavaFX.
It involves complex math and requires Java8 and for you to understand the threading mechanism of Swing and JavaFX, but it seems the optimal option for 3D graphics implemented in Java.
It also [integrates with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) if you require or stands-alone.

Check [Getting Started with JavaFX 3D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/overview.htm)
Check JavaFX [Transformation overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/transformations-intro.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I found this book helpful, it shows you how to create 3D graphics in Java from the ground up:

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Java-Programmers-Ammeraal/dp/0470031603](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470031603)